# Cut and paste to zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I would like to cut and paste a file to a zip archive.
A possible solution would be to first write the file to the zip archive and then delete it.

```
import os
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('demo.zip', 'a') as myzip:
    myzip.write('demofile.txt')
    os.remove("demofile.txt")
```

However, it could be that the file is already opened by another user or process. Is there a way to move the file to zip, only when both writing to the zip archive and deleting the file is possible? Like with cut and paste?

Comment: First move it to a temporary directory, then write it to the zipfile, then remove the temporary file? I assume this is on Windows (cause otherwise it wouldn't make a difference if another user or program had the file open already)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, es, you are right it is on windows.

Comment: Well, you can't cut-and-paste in File Explorer if the file is open in another process either...

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achive. Because currently i would have the file in the zip and could not remove it. Therefore have 2 files (one in the folder 1 in the zip) before it crashes. Id like it to crash before writing to the zip and essentially creating a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make this operation atomic: Either everything succeeds, or everything fails.

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is moving the file away first:

```
import tempfile
import shutil

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    shutil.move("demofile.txt", tmpdir + "/demofile.txt")
    with zipfile.ZipFile("demo.zip", "a") as myzip:
        myzip.write(tmpdir + "/demofile.txt")
```

Now when the file can't be moved/deleted, it will fail at the `shutil.move` line, and nothing has happened to the zip file yet. If the file *can* be moved, nobody has it open anymore and the deletion (which now happens automatically when leaving the `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` context) shouldn't fail.

I'm using `shutil.move` instead of `os.rename` such that it also works across file systems.

Comment: Very, nice thank you. Wasn't aware of the "atomic" definition and themp-file library.